# Symfony 5. Как получить настройки из /configs/services.yaml

Tags: symfony

Всем привет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в тестах получить конфиги из /configs/services.yaml
Документации по сети более, чем достаточно, перепробовал 100500 вариантов - пока безрезультатно.

```
class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private array $params;

    // так работать не будет
    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params, $name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $this->params = $params->get('my_config');;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

К параметрам файла services.yaml можно получить доступ сле. образом:

1. расширить класс WebTestCase
2. добавить статическое поле **public static $client;**
3. в конструкторе (можно и в др. методе):

`$container = self::$client->getContainer();
$params = $container->getParameter('param_name');`